# Is there a cake in portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

I have been wondering if there is a cake in portal 2 or not. I've seen this question raised on quite some forums but nobody seems to be able to answer it correctly. Some say there is, some say they don't. I've seen a few screenshots, but I'm not sure they are real, because most of them are just from portal 1.

So, is the cake real, or is the cake a lie?

Comment: the cake is not a lie. i ate it

Comment: How can it be a lie if it was never promised?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The cake is not real, nor a lie, because

> you are never offered any cake.

The only reference in the entire game can be seen in this video (obvious spoilers)

PS: The new meme is `Lemons`

Comment: Here's one thing I've wondered about that video: Why doesn't GLaDOS just squash us between the panels rather than going through the whole iffy deadly neurotoxin and turret routine?

Comment: This is NOT the only reference.  In co-op, look closely at the text on the monitors at entrance to each course just before the disassembly machines (above the panel that shows your specific progress).  You may need to zoom in.

Comment: @Billare - because those are *panels*, not *crushers*. (She has those too).

Comment: There is also a cake in the cartoons on the wall.

Comment: Lemons? I thought the new meme was potatOS or potato batteries?

Comment: @EricGagnon That's the nice thing about Portal 2. It is no longer limited to one meme.

Comment: @Arda: Well, Portal 1 had cake, companion cube, and "now you're thinking with portals"...

Answer (score 4):

One of the developers said he was tired of the overuse of the cake is a lie meme, so he kept callbacks to it to a minimum.